# Does django debug_toolbar runs with static files stored on S3?

Tags: django, amazon-s3, django-debug-toolbar

My app works well :

1. with S3 and without debug_toolbar
2. without S3 and with debug_toolbar.

But when i combine S3 and debug_toolbar i got one error when loading the **1st** static file loaded on S3.

Error: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    function() argument 1 must be code, not str

```
 <link href="{% static "/css/mycss.css"%}" "" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```